# ionic 4 - livereload does not work

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, livereload, ionic4

Livereload on iOS device (ionic cordova run ios -l) with ionic 4 does not seem to work.
It stuck at the initial loading at splash screen. I've tried with fresh project right after ionic start **** blank, it still does not work.

livereload on browser (ionic serve) and emulator (ionic cordova emulate ios -l) works fine.

ionic info:

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.0.1 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.11

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0
   Cordova Platforms     : ios 4.5.5

System:

   ios-deploy : 2.0.0
   NodeJS     : v8.11.3 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm        : 5.6.0
   OS         : macOS High Sierra
   Xcode      : Xcode 9.4.1 Build version 9F2000


Device info:
iphone X, iOS 11.4 (15F79)
```

does anyone have a clue of how to fix this?

Thank you

Comment: Had the same problem, ran npm uninstall ionic, then ran npm i -g ionic@3.2 and livereload is working again.

Answer (score 3):

Try with below mentioned command

```
ionic cordova run ios --device -lcs
```

Answer (score 2):

A workaround is to run ionic serve from a sudoer user.

```
sudo ionic serve
```

Comment: Work like a charm. Never think it could be on sudo

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this command

```
ionic cordova run browser --livereload --port=4200
```

Answer (score -1):

```
ionic cordova emulate ios --livereload --external
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ this code answers the question improves its long-term value. [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)